# Using @MessageDriven without XML configuration in WAS7.0

Tags: ejb-3.0

As I am using WAS7.0 for Message Driven Bean and i have configured the MDB through annotation. I am not configuring any thing in `ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml` and `ejb-jar.xml` xml and I am giving all configuration in `@MessageDriven` configuration but My MDB is not listening the message from Queue Please advise while using `@MessageDrive` annotation do i need to configured MDB in XML also. I am using below annotation.

```
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge"), 
         @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "useJNDI", propertyValue = "true"),
         @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "connectionFactoryJndiName",propertyValue = "jms/TestChangeSubscriptionConnectionFactory"), 
         @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationJndiName",propertyValue = "jms/ETestChangeSubscriptionQueue") 
 }, mappedName = "jms/TestChangeSubscriptionQueue")
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
```